# Schema of a database by Python

Tags: python, sql, sqlite, database-schema

I am trying to work with the [football database](https://www.kaggle.com/hugomathien/soccer). I have some issues as I am also new to SQL.

1. I would like to have a nice schema diagram for the database and to only use Python, so no GUI-based programs. I tried `ERAlchemy` and `sqlalchemy_schemadisplay` but they are not of great help because the Match table has 115 columns and so the diagram is too big. Also, they don’t show all foreign keys.
   I tried to work around with the following code to create a data frame for each table with columns’ information.

```
import pandas as pd 
import sqlite3 as sq 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import seaborn as sns

db = sq.connect('database.sqlite')
cur = db.cursor()
tables_names = cur.execute("SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table'").fetchall()
tables_info = {}
for name in tables_names:
    tab_name = name[0]
    columns_info = cur.execute("PRAGMA table_info("+tab_name+")").fetchall()
    df = pd.DataFrame(columns_info, columns=['index', 'col_name', 'datatype', 'can_be_null', 'default_val', 'is_PK'])
    df.set_index('index', drop=True, inplace=True)
    tables_info[tab_name] = df
    FKs = cur.execute("PRAGMA foreign_key_list("+tab_name+");").fetchall()
    df['is_FK'] = 0
    df['references'] = 0
    for FK in FKs:
        df.loc[df['col_name']==FK[3], 'is_FK'] = 1
        df.loc[df['col_name']==FK[3], 'references'] = FK[2]+"("+FK[4]+")"
```

I then can have the following information:

[image]

This seems to work but it is not so pretty. Do you have any suggestions?

2. The above picture shows an issue. `The League(country_id)` column references `country(id)` and the `country` table (with lowercase c) is not shown in the list returned by `tables_info`. How can I solve this problem?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: In SQLite table and column names are case insensitive. `Country` is the same as `country`.

Comment: Now it gets more confusing because if you did use `sqlalchemy_schemadisplay`, for example, to visualize the tables, you will find two tables; one named `country` and this is linked to the `League` table, and another one named `Country` and this is not linked to any other table. 

Look at this diagram built with `sqlalchemy_schemadisplay`. The `Country` table is isolated at the bottom of the photo.

https://ibb.co/n8zW04G

Comment: I don't know how `sqlalchemy_schemadisplay` works, but what I'm sure of is that there is only 1 table Country in the database.